# A .css class is not added until the second button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a simple game that gives an RGB color, ie. rgb(247, 237, 237), and ask a player to pick a square that has the closest matching color.  The default mode is Hard mode that ha 6 colored squares, and the easy mode has 3 squares.  So initially each square `<div class="square"></div>` use the .square css class to style. (See .html file below)

So after I started the game, I clicked the Easy mode, my code removed .square css class for the bottom 3 squares.  However, when I change from Easy mode to Hard mode, I need to click the "Hard" mode button "twice" to work.  I found out it's b/c .square css class is only added when it's clicked the "2nd" time. 
My Question: How do I add the .square class the first time I click the Hard mode? (See .js file below marked as: // ===> QUESTION)

.html file:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

.js file:

```
function setupModeButtons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < modeButtons.length; i++) {
    modeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      // If "Easy" Button is clicked,
      if (this.textContent === "Easy") {
        numSquares = 3
        modeButtons[0].classList.remove("selected");
        modeButtons[1].classList.remove("selected");
        this.classList.add("selected");

        // Remove the original bottom 3 squares
        for (var i = 3; i < colors.length; i++) {
          squares[i].classList.remove("square");
        }
        // Reset the top 3 squares
        colors = [];
        generateRandomColors(3);
        pickedColor = pickColor();
        setupSquares();
      } 

      // If "Hard" Button is clicked,
      if (this.textContent === "Hard") {
        numSquares = 6;
        modeButtons[0].classList.remove("selected");
        modeButtons[1].classList.remove("selected");
        this.classList.add("selected");

        // Add bottom 3 squares
        for (var i = 3; i < colors.length; i++) {
          squares[i].classList.add("square"); // ===> QUESTION
        }
        generateRandomColors(6);
        pickedColor = pickColor();
        setupSquares();
      } 

    }); // End of AddEventListener()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `generateRandomColors` is what populates the `colors` array: your issue is that

`generateRandomColors(6);`

runs *after* your

```
// Add bottom 3 squares
for (var i = 3; i < colors.length; i++) {
```

so when there are only 3 colors on Easy, the for loop doesn't run at all the first time the button is clicked.

Just change it to:

```
generateRandomColors(6);
// Add bottom 3 squares
for (var i = 3; i < colors.length; i++) {
  squares[i].classList.add("square"); // ===> QUESTION
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming *generateRandomColors(n)* creates *n* random numbers and stores them in *colors*. So when you click the Hard mode the first time after the Easy mode, colors.length is 3 so the code inside *for (var i = 3; i < colors.length; i++)* won't execute. Change it to *squares.length*